# UITableView embeded in NavigationController and UITabBar won't Scroll

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am currently learning IOS. I have UITableView embedded in NavigationController and UITabBar. I have populated the TableView with data and its showing in the table when I run the app. The TableView is not scrolling and for the life of me I can't figure out why.

Here is the table view code

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{

        return petitions.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
       // code to initialize the cell here

        return cell
    }
```

Any suggestions as to what am missing, or how to make it work is welcomed

Comment: Does your view hierarchy like UITabbarController -> UINavigationController -> UITableView?

Comment: No, its UINavigationController -> UITabbarController -> UITableView

Comment: Your view hierarchy must be like my first comment. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontroller

Comment: I just changed it to match the suggested hierarchy, no effect

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you changed your table view scroll options. So table view is a scroll view. Options must be like below:

[image]

Comment: I just changed the properties as directed. The issue still remains.

Comment: Is the "User Interaction" enabled? Also be sure the frame size of your table view is less than the contentSize of your table view. If frame size is greater or equal to your content size correct your layout constraint of your view.

Comment: Yes, the "User Interaction Enabled" is checked. What am using for the UITableView is the UITableViewController version, not sure, how I am supposed to correct the layout constraint of the table view.